# How to print all EmailTemplate component names using SFDX CLI?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli

I run the below command and it prints undefined.

```
~sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata --metadatatype=EmailTemplate --targetusername=mysandbox --folder=unfiled$public
undefined
```

When I run the above command with `--metadatatype=CustomObject`, it is working fine but not for `EmailTemplate`

What is wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a reserved character in some terminals, so I had to escape `$` like this `--folder="unfiled\$public"`

Here is the complete command that is working:

```
~sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata --metadatatype=EmailTemplate --targetusername=mysandbox --folder=unfiled\$public
```

**NOTE**: I ran into this issue on macOS.

Here is the bash script I created to prepare pacakge.xml with all EmailTemplate component names from the org:

```
#!/bin/bash
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata --metadatatype=EmailFolder --targetusername=devsandbox --json | jq '.result[].fullName' > temp.txt
input="temp.txt"
rm -f package_temp.xml
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" >> package_temp.xml
echo "<Package xmlns=\"http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata\">" >> package_temp.xml
echo "  <types>" >> package_temp.xml
while IFS= read -r line
do
    folderName="${line//\"/}" 
    #folderName="'$id'"
    echo "$folderName"
    rm -f temp_1.txt
    sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata --metadatatype=EmailTemplate --folder=$folderName --targetusername=devsandbox --json | jq '.result[].fullName' >> temp_1.txt
    while IFS= read -r line1
    do
        templateName="${line1//\"/}"
        echo "    <members>$templateName</members>" >> package_temp.xml
    done < "temp_1.txt"
done < "$input"
echo "    <name>EmailTemplate</name>" >> package_temp.xml
echo "  </types>" >> package_temp.xml
echo "  <version>46.0</version>" >> package_temp.xml
echo "</Package>" >> package_temp.xml
cat package_temp.xml
```

Comment: In *some* terminals. It's always worth the time to learn your OS's terminal, as you never know when you'll run in to some quirk of the OS.